# Angular 4 Packages not installing in jenkins,while installation works on ssh with manual package installation, while package.json not working properly

Tags: node.js, jenkins

Hi I am facing issues.

i have mentioned packages required in package.json.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ngui/ngui": "^0.15.2",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.34",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.16.0",
    "angular2-image-upload": "^0.6.1",
    "angular2-promise-buttons": "^1.0.13",
    "angular2-wizard": "^0.4.0",
    "angularx-flatpickr": "^2.0.1",
    "authorizenet": "^1.0.6",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^3.8.0",
    "flatpickr": "^4.5.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng2-bootstrap-grid": "^0.5.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-input-autocomplete": "0.0.10",
    "ng2-inputmask": "^0.2.5",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "poper": "^0.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "systemjs": "^0.21.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.65",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0"
  }
}
```

My node version is 6.11.1 and npm 3.10.10
This works Okay on windows machine but when i try installing it on Ubuntu,
i have to install manually the packages following:

```
npm install @angular/cli@1.0.3 
npm i @angular/router@4.2.6 
npm i @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.2.6 
npm i @angular/platform-browser@4.2.6 
npm i @angular/http@4.2.6 
npm i @angular/forms@4.2.6 
npm i @angular/core@4.2.6 
npm i @angular/compiler@4.2.6   
npm i @angular/common@4.2.6 
npm i @angular/compiler-cli@4.2.6
npm i @angular/animations@4.2.6 
npm i @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.8 
npm i @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.8 
npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.1
```

It works. My question is why my version dependencies are not followed from package.json. Everything regarding angular installs at 4.4.7 which is not right. Also my jenkins fails installing these dependencies.

I want to use jenkins to build these dependencies in the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a shell script for Jenkins

/var/lib/jenkins/testUI.sh

make sure chmod +x permissions are given.

In Jenkins i have called the shell script by giving the above location and in this shell script all packages i wanted installed are mentioned and it works like a charm.

Let me tell you i have also created build by using the following command and pass it in to execute shell in jenkins

node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot false --base-href "/wow/"